# d3 update pattern re-adds instead of updates

Tags: d3.js

I have a vertical stacked bar chart and on `rect` click I want to update the rects, however, it keeps adding instead of updating. Here is the code:

```
var redrawChart = function() {
    //
    // Settings
    //
    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 15 + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    /////////
      //ENTER//
      /////////
    var chartRow = svg.selectAll(".org")
      .data(data);

    var newRow = chartRow
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0, " + y(d.key) + ")"; });

    var rectRow = newRow.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.orgs; });

    var newRect = rectRow
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y1) - x(d.y0); })
      .on('click', function(d){
        console.log(d);
        redrawChart();
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    //////////
      //UPDATE//
      //////////
    chartRow.selectAll('rect').transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y1) - x(d.y0); })
      .attr("opacity",1);

      ////////
      //EXIT//
      ////////
    //Fade out and remove exit elements
    rectRow.exit().transition()
      .style("opacity","0")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .remove();

  };

  redrawChart();
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since you never set the class `org` to anything, `svg.selectAll(".org")` is just like `svg.selectAll("foo")`: your "enter" selection is always full.

Comment: thanks for picking up on that! missed that one! :)